# Rest helper class instances best practice?

Tags: spring, rest

I'm new to rest webservice and have a novice q'.
I've created a rest class and would like to use helper classes to handle certain operations. So for example I've created the following service:

```
import statements...
@Path("/UserResources")
public class UserResource {
    //Create Spring application context
    static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new 
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/spring.xml");
    private UserResourceHelper urh = new UserResourceHelper(); // this is the helper 
    class
UserProfileService userProfileService = ctx.getBean(UserProfileService.class);

@POST
@Path("/createUser")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createUser(@Context HttpServletRequest request, Object object) { 
      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
      User user = userProfileService.findByPrimaryKey(object); 
      sb.append(urh.createUser(object)); 
      return
```

Response.status(Status.CREATED.getStatusCode()).entity(result.toString()).build();
     }
}

I have a couple of questions on this approach:

1. Is this the correct way to instantiate the helper class? Or should I create a constructor and instantiate the class there? for example:

   public UserResource (){
        urh = new UserResourceHelper();
      }
2. On this approach will there always be a new instance of the
   UserResourceHelper?
3. If so that would mean there will not be an issue
   on concurrency correct? ie. 2 requests coming in at the same time
   and the 1st object being received by the createUser method would
   suddenly get replaced by the 2nd object that suddenly came in?
4. I'm using Hibernate for ORM.  Is the way i've instantiated the entities as per my code sample correct?

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Hi all, any feedback to my post would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks